# What is the name of the screensaver daemon on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, screensaver, daemon

My Mac's screensaver seems to be frozen, and I think quitting the process through SSH will resolve the problem. Does anyone know what the name of the process is?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the process is `ScreenSaver` or `ScreenSaverEngine`.